# More than one time encoding and script protection

Tags: php

what about using more than one encoder to encode my code, because if we take a look at [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com) you will see some people can decode it.

my idea here is using non familliar encoder on the encoding code of i**oncube**

i mean i will encode two times

- first with ioncube
- second with any other decoder

is that will make a problem?

Comment: This sounds a lot like "security through obscurity", read up on that. Besides, if the PHP interpreter can read it, so can anyone else (with some minor effort).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would depend on the type of encoding done, if its non destructive, meaning it only obfuscates the code then you probably can run multiple passes, however if it does something more like ioncube, then the person who you would give access to it will need to run both encoders in reverse order to do the decoding.

I dont think it would do any harm, but as far as I know ioncube, encodes the code using a license file which means that even someone with the software cant decode your code without having a license